# Copy kernel images after kernel update

Tags: arch-linux, hook, systemd-boot

I am using ArchLinux on a machine using systemd-boot and UEFI to boot the system. When I receive a new kernel update, the new kernel get's created in my `/boot` , but the UEFI-Boot Partition is mounted unter `/boot/efi` with the files I tell my system to load being in `/boot/efi/EFI/arch/` .

Where can I configure a hook that copies the `.img` files and `vmlinuz-linux` from my `/boot` into my `/boot/efi/EFI/arch/` whenever I update my kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question isn't answered and I came by the same problem/question, I write my own approach, maybe it helps future searchers:

Note that I use Kali and I couldn't confirm that it works, since my kernel is already upgraded(I will update this answer, after I can finally confirm it)

create a file in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` for example `zz_systemd_boot` (the grub-file start with `zz` so I assumed that the files are executed alphabetical) with something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Copy files for systemd-boot

cp /initrd.img /mnt/boot/kali/initrd.img
cp /vmlinuz /mnt/boot/kali/vmlinuz
```

and than make the file executeable`chmod 755 zz_systemd_boot`

Answer (score 0):

using uefi over legacy does not change the location of the kernel images. I use uefi boot loader and my images are all in boot.

For comparison here is my boot partition;

```
$ find /boot/ -type d
/boot/
/boot/grub
/boot/grub/backup
/boot/grub/fonts
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi
/boot/grub/i386-pc
/boot/grub/locale
/boot/efi
/boot/efi/EFI
/boot/efi/EFI/debian
/boot/efi/EFI/boot
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fw
/boot/efi/EFI/grub
```

the directory /boot/efi/EFI contains the uefi boot images;

```
$ find /boot/efi/EFI/ -type f
/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi.bkup1
/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi.old
/boot/efi/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi.old
/boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi
```

the directory "/boot/grub/x86_64-efi" contains all the uefi mod files

```
$ find /boot/grub/x86_64-efi -type f | head -10
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix3.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/date.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/odc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lvm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/font.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/reboot.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/file.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/functional_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ohci.mod
```

and my linux images are all stored in "/boot/"

```
$ find /boot -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "vmlin*" | head -10
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-M1.old
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.5-MX1
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.2-MX1.old
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.5-MXC2.old
/boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-1-amd64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-M1
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.2-MX1
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.5-MX1.old
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-M3
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.5-M1
```

Comment: The location does make a difference if you are using a simple boot manager like systemd-boot instead of Grub.

Comment: The Archwiki recommends simply mounting the UEFI Boot Partition to /boot upon system start, though since in /boot there are already files before configuring stuff, they will be hidden behind the mounted partition and things would propably get wierd. Therefore I mounted in /boot/efi but new images are (obviously) not copied to their relevant locations on their own.

Comment: An alternative is to use a bind mount, as described under "Using bind mount" on Archwiki. It's not without drawbacks, but may work for you.

Comment: The main question would be: Can I delete everything in my /boot directory and just mount my /dev/sda1 to /boot , change a thing here and there in the boot config and be fine with it. I would need to call mkinitcpio once again and the new images would be created on the now mounted partition in /boot ; change the location the bootloader looks up the images and done

Comment: Depends on what you have in there. I'm using `systemd-boot` with an efistub kernel and have mounted the ESP on `/boot`. I have a total of eight files in `/boot`, four of which are installed by `pacman -S linux`, two belong to systemd-boot, and two are configuration files: `/boot/loader/loader.conf` and `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`.

Comment: Well on / I have mounted /dev/sda2 (the linux-fs) and in this /boot there are the vmlinuz-linux etc. . I can hide these files by mounting /dev/sda1 (the ESP) to /boot and let linux install new images to /boot like it used to, but since the ESP is now mounted to /boot it would write them to the other partition. Now since I will actually never have any reason to unmount /dev/sda1 from /boot , I can just simply delete all files from the original /boot directory. That's my logic anyway ...